# Volume of solid enclosed by quadratic surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, analytic-geometry, volume, surfaces

I'm about to enter graduate school and I'm preparing for a placement exam involving some advanced calculus. I found this problem on one of the past exams and I've been stuck on it for awhile.

> Find the volume of the solid that is bounded by the surface $$(x+y+z+5)^2+(x+2y+3z+6)^2+(x+3y+4z+7)^2=9$$

After plotting it in mathematica, I can see that this is a thin ellipsoid:

[image: plot]

My intuition says to integrate over the elliptical cross sections, but I'm having issues setting this up. Some guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: change variables so that you are looking at a sphere of radius 3 - don't forget to multiply by the determinant of the Jacobean matrix of the transformation ( it will be a constant)  . If you don't know about Jacobeans, check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant

Comment: @WW1 Very helpful! I can't believe I didn't think of that. If you'd like to make your comment an answer, I'll go ahead and choose it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After expanding

$$
f(x,y,z) = f = (x + y + z + 5)^2 + (x + 2 y + 3 z + 6)^2 + (x + 3 y + 4 z + 7)^2 - 9 = 0
$$

we can arrange it as

$$
p^{\top}A p + B p + c = 0
$$

with $p = (x,y,z)^{\top}$ and

$$
A = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 3 & 6 & 8 \\
 6 & 14 & 19 \\
 8 & 19 & 26 \\
\end{array}
\right)\ \ \  B = (36,76,102) \ \ \ \mbox{and}\ \ \ c = 101 
$$

Now calculating the $A$ eigenvectors we have

$$
T = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0.314338 & 0.733903 & 1. \\
 -2.7732 & -0.174789 & 1. \\
 0.458862 & -1.55911 & 1. \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Making now the coordinate's change

$$
P  = T p = (X,Y,Z)
$$

we have in the new coordinates

$$
P^{\top}TAT^{\top}P+BT^{\top}P + c = 69.523 X^2+4.30315 Y^2+0.173815 Z^2+169.093 X-11.1191 Y+0.0263806 Z+101.
$$

Now in this coordinate system  we can calculate the ellipsoid three main axes $a,b,c$ and then the volume is the number

$$
V = \frac{4\pi}{3}a b c
$$